# BERT Ensemble shared linear layer worse than individual model

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model

I fine-tuned two bert-base models, initialized with different weights, on the same dataset. I then attempted to combine my pretrained models via a shared linear layer. Supposed there is no problem in my code, is there a possibility that this combination performs worse during training and hence on a test set than the individual models? - This is my situation.

Answer (score 0):

No. The shared linear layer is essentially an ensemble machine learning method, which combines two "weak" models into a single stronger model. The parameters for this combination are learned to optimize performance on the training set, so unless the shared layer is designed in such a way that it doesn't actually utilize the input features, its performance should always be at least as good as the worse of the two ensembled models *on the training set*. This is because at a minimum, the shared layer should be able to learn to output exactly the result of the better model and ignore the other model. Of course, it would be reasonable to achieve worse testing performance as the distribution of the data may differ.

Some causes of your issue may be:

- Initializing in a local optimum
- Different activation function in shared layer
- Other parameter settings

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response DerekG; I will let you know in case I figure it out..